# Rewrite AND/OR query in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

I am having difficulty rewriting AND/OR query in django. Parentheses are banned in django template. I tried using custom tags for this but it doesn't work as expected. Does anyone know how to rewrite a query like this for django templates and for custom tag both? So, I will know where I went wrong.

```
for i in k:
    if (i.first == a and i.second == b)  or (i.first == b and i.second == a):
        {some code}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this exactly expression you don't need parenthesis, order of operations will be exactly the same without them.

Also, if `i` is an instance of some model, you can put this condition check on a model itself (as a `@property`).